# Please help on Ribbon bar style

Tags: css, ribbon

I am working on a SP2010 migrating to SP2013 project. Since the customized Master page cannot be converted directly, I am using the old image and CSS to make up a new Master on SP2013.

When I apply my customized Master page, there is a black bar added below to ribbon bar causing everything descent for a few pixel:

[image: unknown black bar causing everything descent for a few pixel]

I am using IE8 and the developer tool show me "s4-ribbonrow" have these styles applied:

[image]

I think none of them add a black bar. What else I should look into? The black bar don't exist if I change back to oslo Master page.

Comment: Could be an css Overdrive for the class help out?

Comment: does it render like this in other browsers? Is s4-ribbonrow the white background container? If not, I'd inspect that. there may be a thick table border applied only to the top.

Comment: Yes it is same on Chrome. s4-ribbonrow shows background color #21374c as above CSS setup

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but have you tried to remove

```
body #s4-ribbobrow
{
min-height: 43px;
}
```

from the `SharePointDefaultStylesCOREV4.css`

Comment: Just to clarify. You'd want to override that style. Never remove/modify the OOTB files such as `SharePointDefaultStylesCOREV4.css`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken SharePointDefaultStylesCOREV4.css is a custom file neither part of SP 2010 nor 2013, hence I recommended to remove parts of it.